# Render rfc4180 compilant CSV as table

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, csv

Is there a LaTeX package, which would import data from `csv` and honour the quotation escaping?

To be exact I mean one using the rules 1. - 7. of https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2

Neither `pgfplotstable` nor `simplecsv` seem to work - they both incorrectly parse the quoted comma as field separator.

```
column1, column2
value,"A quoted, value"
value2,A value
value3,"a ""value"""
```

Line 1 (of data) results in a `pgfplotstable` error: `Table 'data.csv' appears to have too many column`. Header, lines 2 and 3 render fine.

Desired output is:

```
column1  |  column2
---------+---------------------
value    |  A quoted, value
value2   |  A value
value3   |  a "value"
```

The only solution I found is manually enclosing the fields with `{}` brackets, but it's obviously a hassle.

**EDIT:** in the original file only the fields that contain commas and quotes are quoted

**EDIT2:** I understand it might be complicated to change the quotations to proper '' `` pairs; I'm not interested in this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: would it be OK if we ignore the `"` and join the resulting columns? I mean are there always commas present inside the quotes?

Comment: You can use the [`datatool`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool) package. It parses the data correctly

Comment: Had the same CSV problem; ended up writing a custom exporter for tab-separated values instead - worked right away with `pgfplotstable`.

Comment: Good question.  I also thought I could get away with csvsimple, but, alas, quotes were not supported, and I had a strange issue with special characters like underscore turning into an elevated bullet point, but only in default font.  Anyway, I have the luxury of generating the latex, so I ended up doing a CSV parser in another language and writing straight to latex longtable.

Comment: @Icy - I'd rather either chatnge the csv generation if you control that, or process it with e.g. sed to make it readable to latex tools (the transformation is rather simple)

Comment: @JakubBochenski - to me it doesn't make sense to change the data--if it follows CSV, it is not the data's fault.  If you are writing this changed data to disk as data.csv, how can you share it with someone who uses, for example, Excel?

Comment: @Icy - depending on your particular scenario different approaches are best; If you share the file with other consumers it's probably best to leave it as is. Still, one approach that might be better if you *aren't* generating the latex is to transform the csv to a new file (similar to the PNG/PS double format kludge)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that it is not implemented but can be done with some labor. I've modified the existing macros rather too quickly so Christian should know if I'm breaking anything here. The new setting can be used via `col sep=double quotes`. But it doesn't support another column with quotes as it is an ambiguous character for opening and closing.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}



\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/table/col sep/double quotes/.code = {\def\pgfplotstableread@COLSEP@CASE{7}}}

{%
    \catcode`\ =10
    \catcode`\;=12
    \catcode`\:=12
    \gdef\pgfplotstableread@impl@prepare@DO{%
        \ifcase\pgfplotstableread@COLSEP@CASE\relax
            % col sep=space:
            \catcode`\ =10
            \long\def\pgfplotstableread@impl@DO@##1{\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE##1 \pgfplotstable@EOI}%
        \or
            % col sep=comma:
            \let\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT=\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT@COMMA
            \long\def\pgfplotstableread@impl@DO@##1{\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE##1,\pgfplotstable@EOI}%
        \or
            % col sep=semicolon:
            \catcode`\;=12
            \let\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT=\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT@SEMICOLON
            \long\def\pgfplotstableread@impl@DO@##1{\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE##1;\pgfplotstable@EOI}%
        \or
            % col sep=colon:
            \catcode`\:=12
            \let\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT=\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT@COLON
            \long\def\pgfplotstableread@impl@DO@##1{\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE##1:\pgfplotstable@EOI}%
        \or
            % col sep=brace:
            % allow multi line cells:
            \endlinechar=\pgfplotstableread@oldendlinechar\relax
            \let\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT=\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT@BRACE
            \long\def\pgfplotstableread@impl@DO@##1{\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE##1\pgfplotstable@EOI}%
        \or
            % col sep=tab:
            \catcode`\^^I=12
            \let\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT=\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT@TAB
            \long\edef\pgfplotstableread@impl@DO@##1{\noexpand\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE##1\pgfplotstableread@tab\noexpand\pgfplotstable@EOI}%
        \or
            % col sep=&:
            \let\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT=\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT@AMPERSAND
            \long\def\pgfplotstableread@impl@DO@##1{\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE##1&\pgfplotstable@EOI}%
        \or
            % col sep="
            \let\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT=\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT@DOUBLEQUOTES
            \long\def\pgfplotstableread@impl@DO@##1{\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE##1\pgfplotstable@EOI}%
        \fi
    }%
}%

\long\def\pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT@DOUBLEQUOTES#1"{%
    \pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE@NEXT@{#1}%
    \pgfplotstableread@impl@ITERATE
}%

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=double quotes]{
A,"the comma , and some    space,"
B," followed by another awkward."
}\mytable


\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\mytable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I didn't remove the commas because I am not sure if you need them or not. You can also introduce the quotes again but if that's going to be typeset it's better to use csquotes package or at least ``` `` ... " ```  pairs to render the opening quotes properly.

Comment: OK, I guess I'll just change the input file with sed or something then. I'd rather run another command after generating data, than having to deal with 2 screens of tex magic

Comment: @Jakub: writing parsers is hard in any language and CSV is a really tricky format(e.g. look at the CSV parser written in Java or Ruby). A **complete** parser in awk will be equally awkward.

Comment: @JakubBochenski Your edit is a completely different problem since you need to keep track of the number of " pairs. And the pairs are ambigous because opening and closing quotes are identical. The standard uses double quotes similar to what TeX uses braces for and it's a weird choice in my opinion.

Comment: @Aditya - I just pointed out that in practice I prefer to go with a simpler solution. I'd rather wrap a few lines in my output than use something I don't (want to spend time to) understand

Comment: @percusse - sorry, maybe my question was not clear enough, however I don't agree it's awkward, please check the RFC document http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#section-2 example 7 has exactly this

Comment: @JakubBochenski I know that's the standard but quotes are both internationally have different flavors so it's very easy to screw up and also tedious to maintain when you accidentally skip one in case of nesting, because of the ambiguity I mentioned above.

Comment: @percusse - OK, but my csv is generated anyway

Comment: @JakubBochenski: I didn't mean to say that your example was awkward, but the CSV has awkward grammar. See http://www.secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp